# Wiener $W^n, n=1,2$ process in SDE form

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

G'day, today I have managed to derive $W^n_{t}$ in SDE  form. However I am missing some critical rules to compute $W^1_{t}, W^2_{t}, W^3_{t}, W^{4}_{t}$.

SDE 
$dW^n_{t}
= \frac{n(n-2)}{2} W^{n-2}_{t}dt+ nW^{n-1}_{t}dW_t$

**a) n = 1**
$W^1_{t}
= \frac{1(1-1)}{2} W^{1-2}_{t}dt+ 1W^{1-1}_{t}dW_t = 0 W^{-1}_td_t + W^{0}_tdW_t = W_tdW_t =   ???$

**b) n = 2**
$W^2_{t}
= \frac{2(2-1)}{2} W^{2-2}_{t}dt+ 2W^{2-1}_{t}dW_t = 1 W^{0}_td_t + W^{1}_tdW_t = W_tdW_t + 2W_tdW_t= ???$

Can someone finish what I started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Itô's formula one gets
$$ d W^n_t = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} W^{n-2}_t dt + n W^{n-1}_t dW_t. $$
Now if $n=1$ we have the trivial identity
$$ d W_t = \frac{1(1-1)}{2} W^{1-2}_t dt + 1 W^{1-1}_t dW_t = W^0_t dW_t = dW_t, $$
if $n = 2$
$$ d W^2_t = \frac{2(2-1)}{2} W^{2-2}_t dt + 2 W^{2-1}_t dW_t = dt + 2 W_t dW_t, $$
if $n = 3$
$$ d W^3_t = \frac{3(3-1)}{2} W^{3-2}_t dt + 3 W^{3-1}_t dW_t = 3 W_t dt + 3 W_t^2 dW_t, $$
and if $n=4$
$$ d W^4_t = \frac{4(4-1)}{2} W^{4-2}_t dt + 4 W^{4-1}_t dW_t = 6 W_t^2 dt + 4 W^3_t dW_t. $$

Comment: yeah I've computed it again and it made sense but was confused about the powers. I've posted a new question regarding this subject but in integral form, can you have a look at it as well?