# Wiener $W^n, n = 1,2$ process in Integral form

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

G'day, today I have managed to derive $W^n_{t}$ in Integral form. However I am missing some critical rules to compute $W^1_{t}, W^2_{t}, W^3_{t}, W^{4}_{t}$.

$W^n_{t}
= \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \int_0^{t}  W^{n-2}_{s}ds+ n\int_0^{t}W^{n-1}_{s}dW_s$

**a) n = 1**
$W^1_{t}
= \frac{1(1-1)}{2} \int_0^{t}  W^{1-2}_{s}ds+ 1\int_0^{t}W^{1-1}_{s}dW_s = 0 \int_0^{t}  W^{-1}_{s}ds+ 1\int_0^{t}W^{0}_{s}dW_s = 1 \int_0^{t}W_sdW_s =???$

**b) n = 2**
$W^2_{t}
= \frac{2(2-1)}{2} \int_0^{t}  W^{2-2}_{s}ds+ 2\int_0^{t}W^{2-1}_{s}dW_s = 1 \int_0^{t}  W^{0}_{s}ds+ 2\int_0^{t}W^{1}_{s}dW_s =  t +  2\int_0^{t}W^{1}_{s}dW_s = ???$

**Can I assume here that $t = 1 \int_0^{t}  W^{0}_{s}ds$ ? and if so why ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obtained exactly in the same way as in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3444810/wiener-wn-n-1-2-process-in-sde-form/3444856#3444856). Notice that $W^0_t = 1$, so that in the case where $n=1$ you get $W_t = \int_0^t dW_s = W_t - W_0 = W_t$. What you got for $n=2$ is correct.

Comment: Hey can you explain why $=1∫00$ for n = 2?

Comment: $W^0_t = 1$, then $\int_0^t W_s^0 ds = \int_0^t ds = t$.